# Cannot run g++ compiled code. Get permission error. Used chmod, got Exec format error

Tags: permissions, c++, file-format, code-blocks

I have been using Code::Blocks to write some code and I used cbp2make to generate a makefile that compiles with `g++`. I run `make` and I get all of the ".o" files the makefile promises in the "obj/Release" and "obj/Debug" folders just as if I'd compiled in Code::Blocks. Here's the kicker: I cannot run my code.

If I do:
 `~/<path>/obj/Release$: ./main.o`

I get:
 `bash: ./main.o: Permission denied`.

I've tried `chmod 744 ./main.o`, `chmod 755 ./main.o`, and `chmod 777 ./main.o`. I've also tried w/out the `./`, with `sudo chmod`, and also replacing `7--` w/ `+x` all just for desparation's sake. These change the output of `./main.o` to:

`bash: ./main.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

For reference: `ls -l main.o` returns:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 jiggly jiggly 661344 Sep 8 16:51 main.o` after doing nothing

`-rwxr -xr -x 1 jiggly jiggly 661344 Sep 8 16:51 main.o` after doing `chmod 744`

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 jiggly jiggly 661344 Sep 8 16:51 main.o` after doing `chmod 755`

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 jiggly jiggly 661344 Sep 8 16:51 main.o` after doing `chmod 777`

so `chmod` is working at least ;)

Also, `file main.o` returns `main.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version1 (SYSV), not stripped`. I know at least that my system is "x86-64", but maybe I'm missing some info here?

Obviously, the most important problem I am having is that my code will not run (outside of Code::Blocks) and I need it to. I would really appreciate any help with this. Additionally, I have no clue as to why I'm getting permission and format errors. I would love it if I've missed something obvious, but any solution at all would be helpful and educational.

Comment: It looks like your make file doesn't have a valid link phase / executable target - or if it does, you're not calling it (object files by themselves are not executable - they don't generally have the required entry point to run on their own).

Comment: Ooohhhhhhh! Thank you. The makefile is indeed not linking the object files. It was silly of me to trust it so blindly.